# Buffered Images in java

Tags: java, syntax, compiler-errors

```
static BufferedImage img1[];
for(int i=0;i<60;i++)
   {
     img1[i] = new BufferedImage((int) (width), (int) (height), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    }
```

It shows an error on the line above this code :
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

and below this code as:
 Multiple markers at this line
 - Method breakpoint:Video [entry] - main(String[])
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected

Comment: You are apparently just copying Eclipse messages and only provide a partial snippet of your code. In the snippet here you do never initialize the array, but as the error messages refer to lots of other elements, there is no way to easily help you.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code segment you are pasting, the problem, as stated by others, lies in another portion of your code.

Answer (score 1):

One problem here is that you can't declare a variable which is in the scope of a method to be static. (Or, alternatively, you can't write a for loop which is neither in a method nor a static block.) Fix one of these.

This is a significant difference between C/C++ and Java: In C/C++, you can declare static variables inside functions, and those variables will retain their values across function calls. Java doesn't have that. If you want a variable to retain its value this way, you need to make it a (possibly static) member of a class.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I removed the static declaration but Im kinda still lost. could you please help me figure out my mistake?

Comment: You probably want the for loop inside a static initialiser (surround with `static {` and `]`). But it's a bad idea to have static mutable data.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've got an error in some of your other code.  You've also got an error in this code -- you need to declare the length of the img1 array before using it...

```
BufferedImage img1[] = new BufferedImage[60];
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside questions of style and encapsulation, I suspect the problem is related to *where* you're doing this in a class.

To instantiate the array in a method, you could do something like this:

```
class MyClass1 {
  public void initImages(int width, int height) {
    BufferedImage img1[] = new BufferedImage[60];
    for (int i = 0; i < img1.length; i++) {
      img1[i] = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }
  }
}
```

The array doesn't escape the method, so it will die there.

To instantiate the array as a static member, you could something like this:

```
class MyClass2 {
  static int width = 100;
  static int height = 100;
  static BufferedImage img1[] = new BufferedImage[60];
  static {
    for (int i = 0; i < img1.length; i++) {
      img1[i] = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }
  }
}
```

This uses a static initialization block.

...or this:

```
class MyClass3 {
  static BufferedImage img1[] = initImages(100, 100);

  public static BufferedImage[] initImages(int width, int height) {
    BufferedImage img1[] = new BufferedImage[60];
    for (int i = 0; i < img1.length; i++) {
      img1[i] = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }
    return img1;
  }
}
```

This uses a static method to initialize a static member.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.  You have to declare an array right after the type.

```
static BufferedImage[] img1 = new BufferedImage[2];
```

is the correct syntax.

Here's the edited code from eclipse.  This does compile.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


public class Test {
    static BufferedImage[] img1 = new BufferedImage[60];
    static{
        for(int i=0;i<60;i++)
        {
        int width = 20;
        int height = 20;
        img1[i] = new BufferedImage((int) (width), (int) (height), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        }
    }
}
```

The following problems we're also found:

1. width and height undeclared.  I initialized them to meaningless numbers
2. put the for loop in a static block.  Code can't exist in the class unless it's in a method or a static block of a class.
3. This also necessitated the creation of a class Test.

I'm sure that most of this was due to the fact you only submitted a code snippet.  I've included it for completeness.  This code will create 60 Buffered Images of size 20x20

Comment: Im struggling to read multiple images into an array so that i can acces them.I used this line for a single image,
static BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int) (width), (int) (height), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
it works perfectly. but to make it an array im having trouble.. If i comment out the array iniatlizating and go ahead with single declaration theres no problem in my code and works fine. 
am I doing wrong?
 BufferedImage img1[] = new BufferedImage[60];
    for(int i=0;i<60;i++)
    {
     img1[i] = new BufferedImage((int) (width), (int) (height), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);}

Comment: The square brackets need to be after the type and not after the name of the variable.  That's a c syntax.  Try making it like the above example.  I was able to put your code in eclipse and make it work after making those mods.